# Определение отступов в Figma

Tags: html, css, figma

Есть сверстанная страница https://chrisryana.github.io/toxin/colors-types , в которой ширина центрирующего контейнера равна 1181px - 40px отступы = 1141px, но в макете по которому сверстана страница этот контейнер ~ 1100px. Почему значение ширины контейнера в браузере отличаются от ширины контейнера в макете?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ширину контейнера можно переопределить, вы ее назначали? или она дефолтная  1141? 1141 похожа на дефолтную ширину контейнера bootstrap, только у него 1140

Answer (score 1):

На сверстанной странице блок с классом .container имеет параметр max-width = 1181px. Соотвественно, именно в сверстанной странице, в CSS, ограничена ширина этого контейнера именно этим значением. А значит на достаточно широких экранах ваш контейнер будет занимать 1181px. Вы можете назначить другое значение классу .container, чтобы соответствовать макету:

```
max-width: 1140px;
```

Тогда с отступами по 20px с каждом стороны, у того блока, что вы обвели, на широком экране будет ширина 1100px.